# Android getLocation on install app is 0.0

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location, android-gps

im testing my app in a real device, and a get a error and dont know how to fix.

My app asks for permission to location on android, when install the application asks to allow access.
To locate the position the first time you need to click on the location button.

My problem is this: If GPS is disabled, the app does not find the right position, even after activation, getting as latitude and longitude 0.0.

When you click the button the app checks if it is activated and asks to activate, but even activating the location is the same as 0.0

If you install the app with GPS enabled, this problem does not occur.

Can someone help me?

im using this code to location button

```
 public void btnlocalizacao(View view) {
       gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

    // check if GPS enabled
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    CameraPosition newCamPos = new CameraPosition(new LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                            15.5f,
                            googleMap.getCameraPosition().tilt, //use old tilt
                            googleMap.getCameraPosition().bearing); //use old bearing
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(newCamPos), 2000, null);

                } else {
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
}
```

and this is the gps class

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 ; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true));
                        //location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            Log.d("Localização", latitude + " " + longitude);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
                            //location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                Log.d("Localização", latitude + " " + longitude);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("ALerta de GPS");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS não esta ativado, gostaria de ativar?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Configurações", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is this: If GPS is disabled, the app does not find the right position, even after activation, getting as latitude and longitude 0.0.

It is all works as intended. The fact you are granted location permission means you are permitted to obtain the location **IF and only IF** it is available. It means nothing more, especially it does **NOT** guarantee nor even mean that you will ever get any coordinates from the system (user may i.e. simply do not use GPS receiver).

Comment: But why this dont occur if the GPS is enable?

Comment: Because GPS is enabled.